# python flask disable page for manutention

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

For working in progress reason I need to disabled same page of my project, without change name or comment code. this is my example code :

```
@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')
```

I need a solution like `@disable_page`, when put this on page need show to user page_disabled.html. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
def disabled():
    return render_template('page_disabled.html')

def disable_page(func):
    return disabled

@app.route('/about')
@disable_page
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')
```

The `@disable_page` decorator has to go below the `@app.route`.

Comment: is not possible only on function ?
just def disabled(func):
    return render_template('about.html')